# Mercurial and particular files branching

Tags: svn, mercurial

The context: i have a project, that contains `configs/` directory, which contains (surprise-surprise!) a set of config files: `database.php`, `facebook.php`, `twitter.php`, `cache.php`, etc

What I did in `svn`: I have created branches per specific file and made changes there (changed database connections, facebook API keys, etc). So they were stored in my private branch.

Now I'm trying to migrate to "modern" nowadays DSCM - Mercurial. And I cannot get any possibility of doing the same.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to advices from #mercurial at irc.freenode.org i mentioned to modify my code so personal configs could be loaded from separate directory which is stored in another repo.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `hg branch` to create a private testing branch as well as a development branch and a release branch.

`hg branch mock_settings`

`hg branch dev`

Make your private testing changes on *mock_settings*, merging from *dev* to *mock_settings* to do a settings test.

This compartmentalizes test settings from development from release.

Comment: 1. that branches will be pushed to server too? 2. is it possible to branch only specific file or folder at least?

Comment: For release, I would suggest not publishing the repository, but using a release process. It would `merge` *dev* branch to *release*, `clone` s to a testing VM, `update` s to `release`, then uses `hg archive` feature to produce a released package.

Comment: so if it's a team of 10 developers - wouldn't it be a great headache to follow your advice?

Comment: In the case of multiple developers, each developer can be given a branch to do most of his work on, which gets merged up to dev on review approval - the rest follows.